# ¿Qué es un "pasón" en México?

Tags: méxico, coloquialismos

Estaba escuchando una canción algo gamberra de Molotov llamada "Parásito" del disco Apocalypshit (no sé si la historia me absolverá) y escuché lo siguiente:

> Subieron la **mota**, también el alcohol
>
> Y ahora es más caro ponerse un **pasón**.

Por lo que veo, *"mota"* parece querer decir marihuana. Ahora bien, ¿qué quiere decir ***"pasón"***? ¿Es algo así como "colocarse" de drogas?

Comment: Pasón quiere decir colocón, en este caso de marihuana

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En México, *darse un pase* significa <s>esnifar</s> inhalar cocaína. *Ponerse un pasón*, es una variante de dicha expresión, en la cual se utiliza un aumentativo de *pase*, no sé si correcta o incorrectamente.

*Un pase*, es la dosis de cocaína que se <s>esnifa</s> inhala de una vez. También se le conoce como *grapa* o *raya*.

Comment: Es increíble que la RAE acepte semejante palabreja como "Esnifar". Su uso no es extenso ya que nunca la he oído ni siquiera en tantas películas de narcos que hacen sobre mi país y ya el español tiene las palabras inhalar y aspirar.  Ya que la RAE la acepta, mi edición es "cosmética" y no una correcicón.

Comment: @DGaleano gracias por la edición. Al contrario tuyo, yo si he escuchado muchas veces la palabra "esnifar" y hasta ahora que leo tu comentario es que me doy cuenta que su uso causa incomodidad.

Answer (score 1):

> una sobredosis

Se deriva de "*pasar*", como "*pasar la dosis apropriada*."

Answer (score 1):

Leído en [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/mexico/comments/3pyv82/alguien_puede_explicar_qu%C3%A9_es_un_pas%C3%B3n/):

> "Darse un pase", significa tomarse una dosis de droga: cocaína,
>   heroína, mdma, marihuana...
>
> "Darse un pasón" significa tener una sobredosis de alguna de estas
>   drogas. No particularmente en el sentido de morirse por esa cantidad,
>   sino en cuanto a drogarse mucho.

Comment: Yo difiero en que signfique "sobredosis", ya que nadie busca tener una sobredosis de alguna droga a menos que este intentando suicidarse, por ejemplo. He nacido y crecido en México, puedo opinar con certeza que "ponerse un pasón" es utilizado con el mismo significado que "meterse un pase(inhalar una dosis de cocaina)".

Comment: @JoseMaria ajá, entiendo. Nótese que lo extraje de [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/mexico/comments/3pyv82/alguien_puede_explicar_qu%C3%A9_es_un_pas%C3%B3n/) y después de decir _sobredosis_ se matiza su sentido a  _drogarse mucho_. Es una community wiki, siéntete libre de editarla; o si crees que se aleja mucho, mejor ponlo en tu respuesta, la acepto y borro esta :)

Comment: Sólo quería ampliar un poco los resultados de tu búsqueda desde el punto de vista de un nativo Mexicano. No me parece mal que conserves tu propia respuesta marcada como correcta, ésto es sólo una pequeña aportación a la misma ;)

Comment: @JoseMaria y te la agradezco mucho, pues para mí _pasón_ era algo desconocido.

Comment: ¿Las expresiones siempre van así? O sea, darse/meterse/ponese un pase/pasón, ¿son todos intercambiables?